# Usage of impersonal passive

Tags: passage-request, passive-voice, impersonal

Finding nice impersonal passive example from *Seneca* (*Moral Letters* 30): *ubi plurimis locis laxari coepit [navis?] et cedere, **succurri non potest navigio dehiscenti***, made me ask two things:

1. Could we simply replace the passive *succurri* with the active *succurrere*? If so, what is the difference in meaning? Another example from Cicero ([collected by Mitomino](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13092/infinitival-impersonal-passives/13094#13094)): *Negat Epicurus iucunde posse vivi, nisi cum virtute vivatur* - is it possible to switch to *vivere*?
2. In general, can impersonal passive clause can be the subject and attach with simple verbs like infinitives sometimes do? Like my example: *"malis seccurri, bonos vexat"*?